# Compiling legacy fortran 77 code on a MAC with gfortran: %LOC() causing problems?

Tags: gfortran, fortran77

I am working on compiling legacy Fortran 77 code on a Mac OS X 10.8.4 using gfortran 4.6.2.  The gfortran was installed from http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#MacOS site.

According to the gcc.gnu.org wiki for GFortran, Release 4.2 includes this: 
"The DEC extensions %VAL, %LOC and %REF are now supported."

I am getting the error below when I compile:

```
        IPL(I) = %LOC(R8D(INITX(I)+1))                              
                  1
```

Error: Invalid character in name at (1)

Is there a workaround?

Comment: To what do you set the option `-std` when compiling ?  Check the documentation for what this does and why it might matter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the new intrinsic LOC can be used instead:

> The LOC() intrinsic works the same way as the %LOC() construct

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/LOC.html